# convert Java.util.Date to com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate error

Tags: java, datastax

I have an error when using:

```
protected LocalDate getLocalDate( Date date ) {
    if ( date != null ) {
        return LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch( date.getTime());
    }
    return null;
}
```

if my java.util.Date is say 30-Sep-2017 this get converted and stored in Cassandra table as 29-Sep-2017
however
when I convert LocalDate to java.util.Date using

```
Date interestOnlyEndDate  = 
    new Date(row.getDate("interest_only_end_date").getMillisSinceEpoch());
```

where the row object is retrieved from the DB, the Date is created correctly 
as 29-Sep-2017

Comment: Is the timezone of the machines where the conversion to millis happens before storing to DB and where the conversion back to Date happens same?

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure how to check this but I will have a look. All of the code currently runs on one machine for development purposes

Comment: Hi, The TimeZone on my Mac is set to BST so I set: TZ=BST in the user profile and then restarted Cassandra and Tomcat but still get the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running Tomcat 7.0.57, Cassandra 3.10 and Datastax driver 3.1.4
The default timezone on my Mac was set to BST so I tried setting TZ=GMT in my profile but this was ignored by both Cassandra and Tomcat so I added:

```
-Duser.timezone=GMT
```

to the JAVA_OPTS definition in catalina.sh and it worked perfectly.